# How to bind radio buttons to a vuex store?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I want to one-way bind the value of a set of radio buttons to my model and update the vuex store on change. Unfortunately this does not seem to be documented anywhere. Any help will be appreciated.

Two-way binding works as documented:

```
<input type="radio" name="info-source" value="1" id="info-source-1" v-model="infoSource">
<label for="info-source-1">TV</label>
<input type="radio" name="info-source" value="2" id="info-source-2" v-model="infoSource">
<label for="info-source-2">Social media</label>
```

However vuex starts complaining in this case `Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This [blogpost](https://ypereirareis.github.io/blog/2017/04/25/vuejs-two-way-data-binding-state-management-vuex-strict-mode/) put me on the right track. The solution I came up with is this:

```
<input type="radio" name="info-source" value="1" 
       :checked="infoSource === 1" @change="updateInfoSource(1)">
```

With the `updateInfoSource` method committing to the store.

For a complete example look at the following post: [How to bind radio buttons to a vuex store?](https://notestack.io/public/how-to-bind-radio-buttons-to-a-vuex-store/57ae2735-80b1-4249-923a-13179d4177b4)

Comment: Will the radio get checked on onchecked if the infoSource value is changed programatically? mean is it truely reactive?

Comment: Yes, if the value changes Vuex will take care of updating

Answer (score 21):

As the warning states, you cannot modify the value of the Vuex state object outside of a mutation method.

You can make a computed property which has `get` / `set` methods to reference / update the state of the relevant data in the Vuex store.

Here's a simple example:

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    gender: 'female',
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_GENDER(state, gender) {
      state.gender = gender;
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  computed: {
    gender: {
      get() {
        return this.$store.state.gender;
      },
      set(value) {
        this.$store.commit("SET_GENDER", value);
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/2.3.1/vuex.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" v-model="gender">Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" v-model="gender">Female<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other" v-model="gender">Other<br>
  Vuex store value: {{ $store.state.gender }}<br>
  Computed property value: {{ gender }}
</div>
```

Comment: just as a sidenote, the getter is not necessary of course. You can access the state directly. But getters often make sense

Comment: I tried that, but vuex keeps complaining about `Do not mutate vuex store state...`

Comment: That means you're still, somewhere in your code, updating the vuex store state outside of a mutation method.